# Does font size specified on page body affect its iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, web

I have a page with an iframe.

1. The page has a body size of 81.25% and the font size is em based (i.e. 13px).
2. The page which I load into the iframe has an em based font size, too (i.e. 13px).

Now does the iframe use the parent page body size, i.e. 81.25%, or its default 100% body size?

Comment: I don't think any css attributes are inherited through frames. Should be easy to test for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**  [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uluyed/2/edit)

iframe can't use the parent page CSS

Answer (score 2):

Iframes are completely independent of the pages calling them. Think of it as a window to another site altogether. Unless you use Javascript to pass something in, the page in the iframe doesn't even know it's in an iframe.

So the page in the iframe loads with it's own 100% font size.